# PHP Search in two tables from db

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I would like to search files by name and after the tag.

If the tag assigned to the file matches the word you are looking for, this file is also counted.

I have three tables :

```
tags
id | name

tags_files
id | id_tag | id_file

files
id | name | category
```

Now i only search by name in "files" table.

```
$how_many = $this->wpdb->get_var($this->wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$this->table_files} WHERE name LIKE %s AND category IN ($subcategories)", '%' .  $this->wpdb->esc_like($search) . '%'));
```

Every file has assigned tags in "tags_files" table.

How solve this?

=========================

If want you can add search in category like this:

```
WHERE (tags.name LIKE '%search%' OR files.name LIK '%search%' ) AND ($this->files.category IN ($subcategories))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT files.* FROM files
LEFT JOIN tags_files ON tags_files.id_file = files.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_files.id
WHERE tags.name LIKE '%search%' OR files.name LIK '%search%'
```

Comment: now im a stage, where result they are doubled and DISTINC not help

Comment: GROUP BY files.id

Comment: GROUP BY files.id, files.name work, but one question, because "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM" wrong count records

Comment: For COUNT you should use DISTINCT:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT files.id)